# How do i improve my regex to grep third level domain but not extra character at last?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep, subdomain

This regex greps everything. How can i grep only domain but not extra chars.

```sh
echo "AAAA  cccc.google.com BBBB" | grep -oE "[^\.\n]*((\.[^\.\n]*){2}$)"  --color=always
```

I want `cccc.google.com` to be grepped but not `AAAA  cccc.google.com BBBB`. Adding \b doesnt work.
`echo "AAAA cccc.google.com BBBB" | grep -oE "\b[^\.\n]*((\.[^\.\n]*){2}\b$)\b"  --color=always`

Edit: I forgot to say, i needed for grepping third level and fourth level domains. Here's what i meant:

- `g.google.com` This is a third level domain
- `a.b.google.com` This is a 4th level domain.

My above regex was grepping third level domain but it grepped some other char so i asked question.
Lets say i have `AAAA a.b.c.d.e.g.google.com BBBB` then {3} should give me g.google.com and {4} or {3,4} should give me e.g.google.com while at the same time omitting some unwanted character. My regex does exactly that but there is **extra** character!

So, using this regex(from answer, modified):
`echo "AAAA  d.cccc.google.com BBB" | grep -oE '\w+(\.\w+){2}'`
omits the .com part which my regex doesnt(but it prints exta char :( ). So, could you please modify to work in this case.

Comment: `echo "AAAA  cccc.google.com BBBB" | awk '$0=$2'`

Comment: Since i am making that regex for gf (tomnomnom's gf it wont be useful here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like OP wants an interactive regex (clarified in the comments), that can extract n number of domains where the n is variable.

Something like this should work- `(?:\w+(?:\.|\b)){4}(?=\.\w+(?: |$))\.\w+`

Check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vCGoen/1)

### Usage

- #### With `{2}`

  ```sh
  $ echo "AAAA  a.b.c.d.e.g.google.com BBB" | grep -oP "(?:\w+(?:\.|\b)){2}(?=\.\w+(?: |$))\.\w+"
  g.google.com
  ```

  Captures the 2 subdomains, excluding top level domain (i.e `com`)
- #### With `{3}`

  ```sh
  $ echo "AAAA  a.b.c.d.e.g.google.com BBB" | grep -oP "(?:\w+(?:\.|\b)){3}(?=\.\w+(?: |$))\.\w+"
  e.g.google.com
  ```

  Captures the 3 subdomains, excluding top level domain(i.e `com`)

...and so on

### Explanation

`(?:\w+(?:\.|\b)){3}` <- This is the same as my original answers, it just captures word characters followed by a `.`, exactly 3 times

`(?=\.\w+(?: |$))\.\w+` <- This acts as the stopping point of the previous regex. It marks the start of the top level domain and captures it.

## Original Answer

That regex seems completely wrong, if you want to only match urls like `cccc.google.com` and `www.google.com` but not `google.com`, you should use- `(?:\w+(?:\.|\b)){3}`

Check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7WmMUp/1)

### Explanation

The primary part is `\w+(?:\.|\b)` - this matches word characters that are immediately followed by a `.` or a word boundary (i.e space)

This is enclosed with a `(?:){3}` which makes sure such groups are encountered 3 times.

To also grep 4th level domains, use just change the `{3}` to `{3,4}`

`(?:\w+(?:\.|\b)){3,4}`

Check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7WmMUp/2)

This is how you should do it with `grep`-

```sh
$ echo "AAAA  cccc.google.com BBB" | grep -oP "(?:\w+(?:\.|\b)){3,4}"
cccc.google.com
```

And with `d.cccc.google.com`

```sh
$ echo "AAAA  d.cccc.google.com BBB" | grep -oP "(?:\w+(?:\.|\b)){3,4}"
d.cccc.google.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Just `echo "AAAA  cccc.google.com BBBB" | grep -oE '\w+(\.\w+)+'  --color=always` seems to work. `\w` is more or less what should be expected in domain names.